# Omnet 3D Integration

Tags: omnet++

I have installed the following:

- omnetpp-5.0b3-src-linux.tgz
- osgEarth
- OpenSceneGraph

and trying to run **osg-earh** module, but it gives me the error

> **osgEarth and OpenSceneGraph are not installed**".

Please help me integrate **osgEarth** and **OpenSceneGraph** with **Omnet++**.

Comment: formatting, spelling

Answer (score 0):

- make sure you have followed the InstallGuide.pdf. OSG support requires additional packages installed on your machine. (QT, OSG, osgEarth etc.). The InstallGuide has a full list of the required packages.
- recommended: in configure.user set PREFER_QTENV=yes so QTenv will be your default runtime environment (OSG is available only QTEnv)
- after installing the required packages, run ./configure an make sure that QT, OSG and osgEarth is correctly detected (check the output of the command)
- rebuild OMNET
- try samples/aloha and see whether you are running under Qtenv
- Try the osg-earth example